# Are the Union and Intersection of a family of Topologies, a topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\{T_a: a \in A\}$ be a family of topologies.
Are $\bigcup \limits_{a \in A} T_a$ and $\bigcap \limits_{a \in A} T_a$ topologies of $X$? How to prove?

Comment: No and Yes. What did you try?

Comment: HINT: show that the union of families doesnt imply that the union of open sets of distinct families belong to the union of families. By the other side if an open set belong to the intersection of families then it belong to both families, thus any union of open sets also belong to the intersection, and the same happen for finite intersection.

Comment: Thanks for your response Sir. I am new on Topo.  I tried answering but I am confused figuring out if the intersection is an empty set. If so, then it is a topology. I am not that sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is $\bigcup T_{a}$ a topology?

No. Consider

$$X=\{1,2,3\}$$
$$T_1=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, X\}$$
$$T_2=\{\emptyset, \{2\}, X\}$$

You can easily check that both $T_1$ and $T_2$ are topologies but

$$T=T_1\cup T_2=\{\emptyset, \{1\}, \{2\}, X\}$$

is not a topology. That's because $\{1\}\in T$ and $\{2\}\in T$ but
$$\{1\}\cup \{2\}=\{1,2\}\not\in T$$

> Is $\bigcap T_a$ a topology?

Yes. We have to check topology axioms:

1. Since both $\emptyset\in T_a$ and $X\in T_a$ for all $a\in A$ then $\emptyset\in \bigcap T_a$ and $X\in\bigcap T_a$.
2. Let $\{U_i\}\subseteq \bigcap T_a$. This means that $\{U_i\}\subseteq T_a$ for all $a$. And thus $\bigcup U_i\in T_a$ for each $a$. Therefore $\bigcup U_i\in \bigcap T_a$.
3. Analogously finite intersections are in $\bigcap T_a$. Can you do it yourself?